# How to set class Dynamically on pressed button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I have html buttons with an icon and the icon shall change temporarily whenever the button gets active (pressed). 
The button icons are defined in separate files containing it in different states.

Example: iconA.scss

```
%iconA_state1 { background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,...); }
%iconA_state2 { background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,...); }
.iconA { @extend %iconA_state1; }
.colored .iconA { @extend %iconA_state2; }
```

And the button:

```
<button><div class="icon"></button>
```

The icon files are independent from buttons and can be used for other purposes, so I do not want to have button specific css in the icon files and no "behaviour" like the css :accent selector. Also ideally I do not want to repeat some code like

```
button:active .iconA { ... }
button.differentstyle:active .iconA { ... }
...
```

for every icon.

Current idea is to set the 'colored' class on the button whenever it gets active (pressed) How can I achieve that?

Is there a way to subscribe to css changes in JQuery?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `:active` CSS pseudo class? It seems the perfect solution here. Using JS as a crutch for the UI is not good practice.

Comment: `I do not want to repeat some code like` You could set only `button:active .iconA` but with an `!important` operator, so you don't need to set active style for each of the classes.
But yeah, you don't need jquery for that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope something like that could help:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('button').on('click', function () { 
       $(this).addClass('colored');
   });

});
```